# Radio Buttons in Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

I have a list of games.  Each game has a visiting team and a  home team.  I would like to allow the user to choose either the visiting team or the home team.  So I converted to template fields and put radio buttons in.  But clearly that isn't right.  I need a radio button list, I think.  Because with just radio buttons, they can select both.  is this possible with a gridview?  most tutorials I see only have one radio button in the row, so this isn't the issue.  here is my gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="id_game" DataSourceID="sqlPopulateGames">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="id_game" HeaderText="id_game" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="id_game" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="visitor" SortExpression="visitor">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("visitor") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <br />
                <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("visitor") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="home" SortExpression="home">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("home") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("home") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="game_time" HeaderText="game_time" SortExpression="game_time" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> because with just radio buttons, they can select both.

Not if those radio buttons are grouped in the markup.  Radio buttons are designed to be mutually-exclusive, but they need to know which other radio buttons to be exclusive with.  [The `GroupName` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobutton.groupname.aspx) in ASP.NET is used to set this.

Something like this:

```
<asp:RadioButton GroupName="SomeGroup" ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("visitor") %>' />
```

With that set, this would be mutually exclusive for any other `RadioButton` with the `GroupName` set to `"SomeGroup"`.

Since this is happening inside a repeated control, you probably want a separate group for each iteration.  So you can bind it to some value in the backing data:

```
<asp:RadioButton GroupName='<%# Eval("someValue") %>' ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("visitor") %>' />
```

If `someValue` is unique for each record in the result, then you would end up with a grouped pair of mutually exclusive radio buttons for each row.

Comment: yikes, i guess i should have taken a look at the properties of the radiobuttons.  thanks, that worked